# If a downloaded package verifies, is it safe?

Tags: macos, install, 3rd-party

I'm trying to install the Java JDK. The [download page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) does not use HTTPS. I downloaded the `.dmg` file anyway; when I open it, Finder spends some time verifying it and then I have the option to install it.

How can I know whether it's safe to install?

Comment: I would not trust the Verify... step in Finder, as I'm not sure that actually does security verification (instead I think it just checks that the file has not been corrupted). However you can check the file integrity with [these checksums](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/s/digest/8u144checksum.html) served over HTTPS. (Linked from the install page and will be out of date with new versions). To verify, type `shasum -a 256 ` in a new Terminal window, drag the DMG file in, then hit Return in Terminal. You should get the same sequence as the corresponding one on the linked page.

Comment: Thanks @0942v8653! I didn't see that link to the checksums - and I wouldn't have guessed it would be served over HTTPS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't know.

The finder just checks the disk image is a valid disk image.

To check that what you have downloaded matches what is on the server you need to do more checking. A common way is to calculate a hash on the downloaded data and compare with a hash published by the internet site.

Then how do you know that the app you have downloaded won't format your disk? Again you don't You have to use your judgement as to whether the publisher is trustworthy enough.

If you went to Oracle's page directly or via a link from a trustable source then ok but if from a link from a mail from someone who has never sent you a mail before then probably not a good idea.